# Where can I find a proof of Steinitz theorem regarding an interior point contained in convex set?

Tags: reference-request, convex-analysis, combinatorial-geometry, convex-geometry

It's amazing how hidden this is on the internet, I can only find quantitive theorems which are difficult (they're great, but I want to see the original proof).

I'm looking for a simple proof of Steinitz theorem:
Given a set of size $n$ with an interior point of its convex hull in $R^d$, there is a subset of size $2d$ such that the point is in the interior of the convex hull of the subset.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Sorry, it is the dimension where we live, $R^d$, I'll edit.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio That's not what i'm looking for... I'm aware of Caratheodory's theorem. Note the interior part in my question

Comment: I am noticing the proof of Steinitz theorem mentioned by such Wikipedia page is behind a paywall, but the following one is not: http://csclub.uwaterloo.ca/~jy2wong/jenerated/blog/2013-09-28.steinitz_theorem.html

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Awesome thanks, were you able to find a more formal and less geometric proof?

Comment: I find it pretty formal and I think that geometric arguments are difficult to avoid in proving a statement in convex geometry...

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Well, it's not trivial that the convex hull of finitely many points is the intersection of (the number of points) half spaces. I prefer linear algebric treatments (such as the proof of Caratheodory, even the author admits here it's not formal).